# cryptsetup mistake and fixing a start job is running for no time limit

Tags: systemd, boot, luks, cryptsetup

I was messing with `cryptsetup` to mount a LUKS encrypted volume automatically without prompting for a passphrase (which I was successful in doing) however I naively deleted everything in `/etc/ccryptab` and did a reboot.  Now linux, after prompting for the LUKS passphrase of the booting operating system disk, which it takes successfully, it progresses then hangs at

`a start job is running for /dev/mapper/luks-***  (no time limit)`

It is trying to mount a second disk in the system that is LUKS encrypted, that I mount as `/scratch`

Is there a way to fix this or am I looking at reinstalling linux from dvd?

Or is there a way to mount this disk in another system, which I know I could do, and then what on it can I edit to undo what's causing the hangup?

I am running RHEL 7.9 x86-64.